# Accessing variable in functions

Tags: python

```
from math import sqrt
grades = [100, 100, 90, 40, 80, 100, 85, 70, 90, 65, 90, 85, 50.5]

def print_grades(grades):
    for grade in grades:
        print grade

def grades_sum(grades):
    total = 0
    for grade in grades: 
        total += grade
    return total

def grades_average(grades):
    sum_of_grades = grades_sum(grades)
    average = sum_of_grades / len(grades)
    return average

def grades_variance(scores, average):
    variance = 0
    for i in range(len(scores)):
        variance += (average - scores[i])**2
    return float(variance)/len(scores)

def grades_std_deviation(variance):
    grades_variance(grades,grades_average(grades))
    return sqrt(variance)

print grades
print grades_sum(grades)
print grades_average(grades)
print grades_variance(grades, grades_average(grades))
print grades_std_deviation(grades_variance(grades, grades_average(grades)))
```

For the last print section, is there any way to not have to call the function within each function? For example, in "print grade_std_deviation" I need to nest the variance and average function inside. Is there any way for the grades_variance and grades_average function to "return" a variable that is accessible outside the respective function's scope?

Comment: They, um.. *do* return a variable..

Comment: Why not store the returned variables instead of calling twice?!

Answer (score 4):

Why not just store the results in variables like this

```
avg = grades_average(grades)
var = grades_variance(grades, avg)
dev = grades_std_deviation(var)

print avg, var, dev
```

Answer (score 1):

The functions do return *variables*, you only need to store them.

```
print grades

g_sum = grades_sum(grades)
g_avg = grades_average(grades)
g_var = grades_variance(grades, g_avg)
g_dev = grades_std_deviation(g_var)

print g_sum
print g_avg
print g_var
print g_dev
```